# How to get the next randomly generated parent ID using Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```html
<table class="ui-table Schedule detailed">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="Row00000" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00001" class="Schedule-row 0 odd" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00002" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00003" class="Schedule-row 0 odd" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00004" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00005" class="Schedule-row 82 odd" data-Schedule-id="82">
<tr id="Row00006" class="Schedule-row 80" data-Schedule-id="80">
<tr id="Row00007" class="Schedule-row 79 odd" data-Schedule-id="79">
<tr id="Row00008" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00009" class="Schedule-row 0 odd" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00010" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00011" class="Schedule-row 0 odd" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00012" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00013" class="Schedule-row 0 odd" data-Schedule-id="0">
<tr id="Row00014" class="Schedule-row 0" data-Schedule-id="0">
<td class="hidden col-id-personNo" data-col-id="personNo"/>
<td class="active w130 col-id-TsDate indicate first yellow" data-col-id="TsDate">
<td class="hidden w100 col-id-StartTime" data-col-id="StartTime"/>
<td class="active col-id-TaskId" data-col-id="TaskId"/>
<td class="hidden col-id-OriginalKey" data-col-id="OriginalKey"/>
<td class="hidden col-id-ScheduleId" data-col-id="ScheduleId"/>
<td class="hidden col-id-TsStatus" data-col-id="TsStatus"/>
<td class="hidden col-id-Quantity" data-col-id="Quantity"/>
<td class="active check w25 col-id-Selected" data-col-id="Selected"/>
<td class="active buttons col-id-RowButton" data-col-id="RowButton"/>
</tr>
<tr id="Row7d6251f9-f6ea-48bb-90fb-356725307245" class="Schedule-row -1 new odd" data-Schedule-id="-1">
```

I have this code. Basically I have a table with a lot of rows. Using Webdriver (Java) I can click a button and then a new row will be generated with random ID (In this case Row7d6251f9-f6ea-48bb-90fb-356725307245).

***Case 1:***  I know that the first row will always be fixed number Row00000.  I can use while loop and increment the number until I don't get Row00015. That means the last fixed row number is Row00014.  I can take take Row00014 as my base reference and the next parent is what I want.

How to jump to next parent (ignoring all children belonging to Row00014) and get the newly randomly generated ID ?

***Case 2:*** In case the table is empty, whenever Webdriver clicks a button, it creates a newly randomly row id.

```html
<table class="ui-table Schedule detailed">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="Row7d6251f9-f6ea-48bb-90fb-356725307245" class="Schedule-row -1 new odd" data-Schedule-id="-1">
```

In this case, I won't have any base reference. How can I search for that new row with dynamic random id ?

Thank You.

Comment: What you mean by  `jump to next parent (ignoring all children belonging to Row00014)`?

Comment: I think dynamic xpath can help you. But for that you need some prerequisite. Can share any pattern like Row7d6251f9-f6ea-48bb-90fb-356725307245 means Row7 or Row00007 is the button on which you have click or same thing or id is generating without any pattern

Comment: what is the data-Schedule-id if you click on 2 or 3 button.. is it like data-Schedule-id=2 for 2nd click or something.. Actually it is done by your JS so can't say how it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below locators

For case-1

```
By.xpath("//tr[@id='Row00014']/following-sibling::tr[1]")

Or

By.cssSelector("tr#Row00014+tr[id*='Row']")
```

For case-2

```
By.cssSelector("table[class*='Schedule'] tr[id*='Row']");

Or

By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'Schedule')]//tr[starts-with(@id,'Row')]")
```

Comment: He didn't mean literally Row00014... that was just an example. He needs to find the first randomly generated id.

Comment: He has mentioned "I can take take Row00014 as my base reference", thats why I've hard coded it.. btw, I've just posted answer to give some idea on how to construct xpath in that case, not exact answer.

Comment: @JeffC, Santoshsarma,  Thank you so much. For case 1, it works well. I am still working for case 2. No worry, I understand that Row00014 is just an example.  Just wondering in `By.cssSelector("tr#Row00014+tr[id*='Row']")`  , does `+tr[id*='Row']` mean jump to the next sibling and ignore the children? Cheers.

Comment: @keylogger my answer should work for both cases... you're finding it doesn't work for case 2? Please leave a comment on what is not working.

Comment: @keylogger : Did u try with above locators that I've posted for case-2? Is it not finding that element ? Is it throwing any exception while trying find element with above locators ?

Comment: Hi all. Yes, both solutions from Santos and Jeff work perfectly for both cases. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML provided, the new row always has the class "new." With that info, you can use the code below.

```
WebElement newRow = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr.new"));
// do something with newRow, e.g. newRow.click(), etc.
```